# In Python, what operator to override for "if object:"?

Tags: python, object, operator-overloading

I find it very handy to check if an object is "empty" with the following construct:

```
l=[]
if l:
     do_stuff()
```

For a standard python list, the `if` will be executed only if the list is not empty.

My question is, how can I implement the same idea for my own objects?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Define a method `__bool__` (Python 3.x) or `__nonzero__` (2.x). Or define both for portability, with one returning the result of the other.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: I believe `__bool__` was added later. They should perform the same, defining both with one just calling the other should be safe.

Comment: `__nonzero__` is Python 2.x, `__bool__` is Python 3.x.

Comment: @delnan: I thought they backported `__bool__` to 2.6, but apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: Indeed, the change is documented here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html . I guess `__bool__` makes more sense for non collection types.

Answer (score 19):

Implement [`__nonzero__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) for Python 2 and [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) for Python 3:

```
class AlwaysTrueObject:
    def __bool__(self):
        return True
    __nonzero__ = __bool__
```

Comment: `__nonzero__ = __bool__` has the same effect.

Answer (score 10):

If you implement `__len__` Python will do that for you under the assumption that a length of 0 means that the object has a boolean value of `False` and that it has a boolean value of `True` otherwise.

If it makes no sense to implement `__len__`, you can implement `__nonzero__` (or `__bool__` in 3.x (only the name has changed)) which is supposed to return either `True` or `False` depending on the boolean value of the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree it makes no sense to implement __bool__ if __len__ is already there and does the trick.